# highcharts bubble change series name

Tags: charts, highcharts, series

I create a graphs on my site. It get the information from my db mysql and so It always update.

Now I want create, for each user of my site, a bubble chart with the visit, like and comment to every post.

Now my problem is that I want to rewrite the legend (Now the script write Series 1, series 2,...) with the name of my user.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Give us something concrete to work with. Show us the part you're having trouble with.

Comment: Give the series a name like,
name: "xyz"

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your series a [name](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.name) value. Without seeing your code or how you are pulling this data back I cannot really offer more help.

Answer (score 1):

in series:

```
[{ 
   name: 'any name',
   data
},
{
   name: 'name2',
   data
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use labelFormatter whcih allows to customise labels in a legend http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter